After creating two thread pools with ThreadPoolExecutor, how can I use loguru to log each task to a separate log file?
Here is my code:
from loguru import logger
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import json
import os

from my_project.model import My_model


app = Flask(__name__)
flask_port = 1234
HEADER = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

executor_1 = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
executor_2 = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)


def run_model(data):
    model = My_model(data) # in My_model, loguru is used to log info too.
    output = model.main()

    return output

def task_callback(future):
    result = future.result()
    if result['code'] == 200:
        dict_data = {
            "task_id": result['task_id'],
            "data": result['data'],
            "success": 1
            }
    else:
        dict_data = dict_data = {
            "task_id": result['task_id'],
            "data": None,
            "success": 0
            }
    json_data = json.dumps(dict_data, ensure_ascii=True)

    back_end_url = "http://123.123.55.65:5588/backend"
    response = requests.post(url=back_end_url, headers=HEADER, data=json_data, timeout=None)
    
    logger.debug(f"call_back response text: {response.text}")
    logger.remove()

@app.route('/service/model_input', methods=['POST'])
def submit_task():
    data = request.json
    task_id = data['task_id']

    # Name and create log files based on the time the model receives the task and its id.
    log_dir = "/app/log"
    logger.remove()
    logger.add(f"{log_dir}/{{time}}_task_{task_id}.log", 
                   level="DEBUG",
                   backtrace=True,
                   diagnose=True
                   )

    os.makedirs(log_dir, exist_ok=True)

    platform = data['platform']

    if platform == 'platform_a':
        future = executor_1.submit(run_model, data)
    elif platform == 'platform_b':
        future = executor_2.submit(run_model, data)
    else:
        return jsonify({'status': 'invalid platform',
                        'taskid': data['task_id'],
                        'platform': data['platform'],
                        'code': 400})
    
    future.add_done_callback(task_callback)
    return jsonify({'status': 'task recieved', 'taskid': data['task_id'], 'code': 202})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Service enabled.")
    WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', flask_port), app).serve_forever()



When I initiate multiple tasks, for example, two tasks from each of two platforms, resulting in each thread pool receiving two tasks, four logs will be created. However, I notice that each log records all task information from creation until the corresponding task ends (usually lasting about 20 minutes). I want each log to only record information related to its corresponding task_id. How should I adjust the code?
T tried to use the bind() method to bind the task and its log handler, but the log file still looged all the info from all the tasks when its corresponding task was running.

use contextual information and dynamically add and remove handler and dont user logger.add() globally
